# Refer to objects within a loop in php

Tags: php, class, iteration

I would like to use a for loop to access 10 objects of the same class.
The reason is that I want to make a table of the data and I don't find it proper to write by hand all the html markup for each row (object) on the table.

My code is :

```
<?php 
    for ($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){
?>
        <tr>
            <td><? echo $i;?></td><td><?php echo $office1->pc;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $office1->pc*$office1->pcPowerPerUnit;?></td>

            <td><? echo $office1->printer;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $office1->printer*$office1->printerPowerPerUnit;?></td>

            <td><? echo $office1->lights;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $office1->lights*$office1->lightsPowerPerUnit;?></td>

            <td><? echo $office1->aircondition;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $office1->aircondition*$office1->airconPowerPerUnit;?></td>

            <td><? echo $office1->server;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $office1->server*$office1->serverPowerPerUnit;?></td>

        </tr>
     <?php } ?>
```

What I thought that could be done is to change the references $office1->pc (for example) to $office[$i]->pc or something like that but that doesn't seem to work. I also searched for object iteration in the php manual but that wasn't helpful.

The number of objects is fixed (10) and the properties are already calculated and ready to be echoed out.

Comment: You need to tell us, what $office1 is? is it an object, or array?

Comment: Are all the objects named the same, basically $office1, $office2, and so on?

Comment: Yes you can do `$office1[$i]->pc` as long as it is an array that contains an object. what the issue probably is, is that you are throwing html into your php. You need to close the php tag after the `for` loop

Comment: You have a spelling mistake $office1} IN <?php echo $office1}->pc;?>

Comment: Are you sure you need to have 10 objects?  (As opposed to having one object and re-using it 10 different times...)

Comment: Put your office objects into array and iterate though them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a special syntax to refer to your variables like that. Ty this:

`<?php echo ${'office'.$i}->pc;?>`

Answer (score 1):

Use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
    // ...

    $officeVar = 'office' . $i;

    // Now you can use $officeVar as a variable variable:
    $$officeVar->pc;
    // equivalent to:
    $office1->pc;
    // when $i == 1

    // ...
}
```

Comment: well, thank you. Actually the variable variables are very helpful at that occassion as I can see but I used the ${'office'.$i}->pc trick and it worked just fine.

Comment: @SotirisGanouris: The `${'office' . $i}->pc` syntax is basically doing the same thing, only without the temporary variable.  It's all dynamic variable name resolution.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach( array( $office1, $office2, $o3, $o4) as $o ) {
    ?>
    ...
         ... <?php echo $o->pc;?> ...

<?php
}
```

Extend the array as needed.  Object variables hold a handle refering to the object so this is a cheap operation and not a copy.

Answer (score 1):

First of all store the column output values into an array:

```
$columns = array($i, $office->pc, $office->pc*$office->pcPowerPerUnit, ...);
```

you can then output the columns independent to the values in your variables:

```
echo '<tr><td>', implode('</td><td>', $columns), '</td></tr>';
```

The only thing left is that you iterate over all those variables you have. Taken an array is much better than using `$office1` to `$office10`:

```
foreach($offices as $i => $office)
{
    $columns = array($i, $office->pc, $office->pc*$office->pcPowerPerUnit, ...);
    echo '<tr><td>', implode('</td><td>', $columns), '</td></tr>';
}
```

Done. However if you don't want to change due to some reason (e.g. not changing too much at once), you can do similar:

```
foreach(range(1, 10) as $i)
{
    $office = ${'office'.$i};
    $columns = array($i, $office->pc, $office->pc*$office->pcPowerPerUnit, ...);
    echo '<tr><td>', implode('</td><td>', $columns), '</td></tr>';
}
```